# From many pyspark columns (with certain condition) to one column with all the conditions combined. PYSPARK

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have one Python list with some PySpark columns which contains certain condition. I want to have just one column that summarizes all the conditions I have in the list of columns.

I've tried to use the sum() operation to combine all the columns but it didn't work (obviusly). Also, I've been checking the documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html
But nothing seemed to work for me.
I'm doing something like this:

my_condition_list = [col(c).isNotNull() for c in some_of_my_sdf_columns]

That returns a list of different Pyspark columns, I want just one with all the conditiones included combined with the | operator so I can use it in a .filter() or .when() clause.

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

PySpark wouldn't accept a list as to `where/filter` condition. It accepts either a `string` or `condition`.

The way you tried wouldn't work, you need to tweak certain things to work on it. Below are 2 approaches for this -

```
data = [(("ID1", 3, None)), (("ID2", 4, 12)), (("ID3", None, 3))]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "colA", "colB"])
df.show()

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

**way - 1**

```
#below change df_name if you have any other name
df_name = "df"
my_condition_list = ["%s['%s'].isNotNull()"%(df_name, c) for c in df.columns]

print (my_condition_list[0])
"df['ID'].isNotNull()"

print (" & ".join(my_condition_list))
"df['ID'].isNotNull() & df['colA'].isNotNull() & df['colB'].isNotNull()"

print (eval(" & ".join(my_condition_list)))
Column<b'(((ID IS NOT NULL) AND (colA IS NOT NULL)) AND (colB IS NOT NULL))'>

df.filter(eval(" & ".join(my_condition_list))).show()
+---+----+----+
| ID|colA|colB|
+---+----+----+
|ID2|   4|  12|
+---+----+----+

df.filter(eval(" | ".join(my_condition_list))).show()
+---+----+----+
| ID|colA|colB|
+---+----+----+
|ID1|   3|null|
|ID2|   4|  12|
|ID3|null|   3|
+---+----+----+
```

**way - 2**

```
my_condition_list = ["%s is not null"%c for c in df.columns]
print (my_condition_list[0])
'ID is not null'

print (" and ".join(my_condition_list))
'ID is not null and colA is not null and colB is not null'

df.filter(" and ".join(my_condition_list)).show()
+---+----+----+
| ID|colA|colB|
+---+----+----+
|ID2|   4|  12|
+---+----+----+

df.filter(" or ".join(my_condition_list)).show()
+---+----+----+
| ID|colA|colB|
+---+----+----+
|ID1|   3|null|
|ID2|   4|  12|
|ID3|null|   3|
+---+----+----+
```

> Preferred way is way-2